# ngrx selector return same values multiple times

Tags: rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-selectors

I have a

```
export const selectIDs = creteSelector(
    selectorFeature,
    (feature: Feature) => {
        return feature?.metadata?.ids || []
    }
}
```

in the component I have

```
this.store.select(selectIDs).subscribe((ids) => dosomething(ids))
```

When the system is up feature is `undefined` so `[]` is passed into the callback. Then feature then changes to a normal value but `.metadata` not available so select returns [] which is same as last result so the `dosomething()` call back is not supposed to be called. But it actually get called again in my code with []

My question is if both time selector returns a [], shouldn't the calllback (those calls in `subscribe`)be called once?

Or generally I mean if I do this:

```
this.store.select(featueSelector).subscribe((feature) => console.log(feature)
```

suppose global state changes 10 times, but feature stays same so featureSelector returns same feature, will the `console.log()` be called 10 times? I imagine the console.log() will only be called when what feature selectore returns is different from last time?

Thanks

=================== updated =============
it turns out `this.store.select()` returns a `observable`, so when the obserable calls the `next()`, `console.log()` will be called.

Ngrx selector memorize means it directly returns same value if input is same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector is fired again, and a new array instance is returned.
Because `[] === []` is falsy, the new instance is passed to the subscribe method.

As a workaround, you can:

- filter our empty array: `this.store.select().pipe(filter(arr => arr.length > 0 )).subscribe())`
- use the distinct operator: `this.store.select().pipe(distinct(insertCheckHere)).subscribe())`
- I think you can also create a variable `const empty = []` and return `empty` in the selector instead of `[]`

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your help. Yes the original problem is I `return feature?.metadata?.ids` which causes problems because the user call `.length` on list directly which causes crash. That's why I change to `return feature?.metadata?.ids || []` and then found `same` [] get called 3 times. I'll try define a const.

Comment: for second option 'this.store.select().pipe(distinct(insertCheckHere)).subscribe())' my selector is number type then how can i give code for distinct function 'insertCheckHere'